# Can I Copy another assembly to replace my assembly in .Net

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have one exe which calls a dll.The code in dll needs to replace the same dll and exe with another version of exe and dll on same path.Is it possible?In short I need to restore different the exe and dll on runtime.

Regards,

Sachin K

Comment: What have you tried?  What problems have you encountered?  Is your question simply whether it is possible or not? (I'm guessing it isn't...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible. Use *third* EXE that kills your current EXE (`version 1.0`)  and after kill, copies new version of your EXE (`version 2.0`) and all DLLs it needs.

Comment: @sachin: yes, a kind of _updater_ as Tigran told you (+1 for him).

Comment: Thanks The Dll will execute the third party exe.The hird party will terminate the running exe and its dependencies and rest will overrite the exe and paths...I suupose this is ur suggestion.